# How to organize my spec files?

Tags: node.js, testing, tdd, mocha.js

I'm using [mocha](http://visionmedia.github.com/mocha/) to test my node.js application.

I notice that my spec files getting bigger and bigger over time. Are there any pattern to organize the test files (e.g. one specs file per test)? Or are there other frameworks on top of mocha to help me structure the tests? Or do you prefere other test frameworks for that reason?

Answer (score 1):

Large test/spec files tend to mean the code under test might be doing too much. This is not always the case though, often your test code will always out weigh the code under test, but if you are finding them hard to manage this might be a sign.

I tend to group tests based on functionality. Imagine if we have `example.js`, I would expect `example.tests.js` to begin with.

Rather than one spec called `ExampleSpec` I tend to have many specs/tests based around different contexts. For example I might have `EmptyExample`, `ErrorExample`, and `DefaultExample` which have different pre-condidtions. If these become too large, you either have missing abstractions, or should then think about splitting the files out. So you could end up with a directory structure such as:

```
    specs/
        Example/
            EmptyExample.js
            ErrorExample.js
            DefaultExample.js
```

To begin with though, one test/spec file per production file should be the starting point. Only separate if needs be.

Comment: then how do I run it? I'd like to 'mocha testAll.js'. testAll.js will include all sub tests. How do I achieve this?

Comment: I have the same question on how to include sub-tests.  So far it looks like you need to require mocha and use it programatically in order to include other tests without breaking things.  Either that or use --recursive on the command line to pick up all the files.

Comment: @NicolasS.Xu really late reply but all your specs could (should?) be commonjs modules that you require into a subfolder-level `index.js` that actually invokes your specs. It works great in conjunction with npm scripts.